# Sort ArrayCollection with OrderBy Annotation issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many, arraycollection

I'm trying to sort an ArrayCollection in a specific order from the retrieved entity but the @ORM\OrderBy won't fire.

Showcase.php:

```
/*...*/
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/** @ORM\Entity **/
class Showcase
{
    /*...*/
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ShowcaseGelato", mappedBy="showcase", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"}) **/
    private $gelatos;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->gelatos = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /*...*/
```

ShowcaseGelato.php:

```
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
*/
class ShowcaseGelato
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Gelato", fetch="EAGER")
     */
    private $gelato;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Showcase", inversedBy="gelatos")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="showcase_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $showcase;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;
```

ShowcaseController.php:

```
/*...*/
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $showcase = $em->getRepository('TodaysGelatoBundle:Showcase')->find(1);
        return $this->render(
            'TodaysGelatoBundle:Showcase:index.html.twig', array(
                'showcase' => $showcase,
            )
        );
    }
```

And the results are:
[image]

What am I missing? Any help would be apreciated.

Database project view: [image]

Comment: can you give there full ShowcaseGelato without getters and setters?

Comment: @Franky238: updated
you can also look up my repository: [link](https://github.com/tszymanek/gelato/tree/master/src/Szymanek/Bundle)

Comment: One what can i advice you: Try to dump sql what doctrine do on your database. I can't see mistake

Comment: @Franky238: I solved it by refactoring `$showcase = $em->getRepository('TodaysGelatoBundle:Showcase')->find(1);` to `$showcase = $em->getRepository('TodaysGelatoBundle:Showcase')->findOneBy(array('id' => 1));` but it doesn't make any sense. Funny

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek I would suggest reporting this on [the Doctrine2 issue page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/projects/DDC)

Comment: @TomaszSzymanek can you try add this before ShowcaseGelato class:`/*** @ORM\Table()*/` and try use `find` function

Comment: @Franky238: I did as you wrote and the ArrayCollection order remains unchanged. Guess I'm gonna report this as Wilt suggested.